# How to install Cuda in a Vagrant box, for optimus enabled laptops?

Tags: ubuntu, cuda, vagrant, vmware, nvidia

I have performed a pci pass through on the vagrant config, enabled 3D acceleration. Installed Cuda, and tried to run the deviceQuery Cuda example, but unfortunately it tells me it can't pick up a device.

```
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

cudaGetDeviceCount returned 38
-> no CUDA-capable device is detected
Result = FAIL
```

The card is a GF 740M, the driver is nvidia-352, I am using Ubuntu 14.04 in the Vagrant box. In vagrant:

lspci shows:

```
$ lspci -nn | grep '\[030[02]\]'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter [80ee:beef]
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 740M] [10de:0fdf] (rev a1)
```

bumblebeed:

```
$ bumblebeed
[  137.087712] [ERROR]No integrated video card found, quitting.
```

What could I be doing wrong? I can't believe how difficult it is to get nvidia drivers/cards working in a virtualization environment.

Answer (score 2):

Vagrant is a virtual machine manager and uses Virtualbox as it's underlying VM. You would need PCI passthrough to support direct hardware with Virtualbox. Further you need support from:

1. CPU
2. motherboard
3. BIOS
4. Nvidia driver support
5. a host graphics card
6. probably a custom kernel.

Since you stated you have a 740M, which is a mobile GPU, I'm going to assume that you don't have 1,2, 3, 4, and 6. Even if you did have 1,2, and 3 (such as a T430 with a i7-3520m and QM77) it [wouldn't work.](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/can-t430-use-vt-d-passthrough-to-the-nvidia-gpu-for-client-os-for-3d-applications.715098/)

In other words, I don't think it's possible for you to do this. Depending on what you need to do, you can use Docker with GPU support of switch to Xen and maybe that'll work.